# Python While loop inside a for loop that keeps on repeating while value is invalid

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, repeat

This is my code:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    try:
        grade = int(input("Please enter {}'s grade for practical assessment {}: ".format(name, i)))
        while (grade < 0 and grade > 40):
            print("That is not a valid grade.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a valid value.")
        continue
```

My question is that how to check if the grade is in range and to make the loop repeat if a false input is entered. When I tried to run the program, and enter an over range input, it goes to the next assessment number instead of trying again until it's true.

Comment: Right now you have grade needing to be less than 0 AND greater than 40, which will never be true so the While loop will always break out. You also need to get new input in your while loop. Maybe you want an OR instead of an AND?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this which uses a `while True` loop as well as a [`try statement and except clause`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to determine whether the user entered a valid grade:

```
names = ["Adam", "Bob", "Chloe"] # Example list of names

for name in names:
  for i in range(1, 5):
    while True:
      try:
        grade = int(input("Please enter {}'s grade for practical assessment {}: ".format(name, i)))
        if not (0 <= grade <= 40):
          raise ValueError()
      except ValueError:
        print("Error: Please enter a grade between 0 and 40")
      else:
        break
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter Adam's grade for practical assessment 1:  a
Error: Please enter a grade between 0 and 40
Please enter Adam's grade for practical assessment 1:  -1
Error: Please enter a grade between 0 and 40
Please enter Adam's grade for practical assessment 1:  10
Please enter Adam's grade for practical assessment 2:  4
Please enter Adam's grade for practical assessment 3:
...
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/GpZw/0)

Comment: Wow, nice code. Thanks for that as I'm still a rookie in python.